# copy(): Filename cannot be empty error (only occasionally)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a strange php issue.
I have a custom front-end post submission form for WordPress. It most of the time but the other times it seemingly at random doesn't work.

My PHP error log spits out the following:

```
PHP Warning:  copy(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/y567889/public_html/wp-content/themes/colormag/inc/front_deck.php on line 1071

PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://ygoprodeck.com/pics/Trinity World Chalice-deck-14461.png): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in /home/y567889/public_html/wp-content/themes/colormag/inc/front_deck.php on line 1025

PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/y567889/public_html/pics/Trinity World Chalice-deck-14461.png): No such file or directory in /home/y567889/public_html/wp-content/themes/colormag/inc/front_deck.php on line 172
```

So in theory, a user could submit 10 posts. Sometimes 2 of those posts would generate with errors (missing featured image etc etc) with the above error in the php log.

**What I have tried:**

Changed `copy()` to `move_uploaded_file()` with no joy.

Changed permissions on the "pics" folder to 775.

It occurs to one of my users in particular. It happens him with every post he attempts to upload. Generating a new WP account fixes this for him (although it still fails occasionally as per usual).

Because the error starts at line 1017 I'll show what the code is for that:

```
function moveYdktoDeck($ydkId,$postid){
     $ydkUrl = wp_get_attachment_url( $ydkId );

    $newfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/UploadedDecks/3/'.$postid.'.ydk';

    copy($ydkUrl, $newfile) 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `wp_get_attachment_url` can return `false`. Check that before you use it in copy function.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. Although, does that explain why it would only work some of the times? That's the part I can't understand. In theory, it should always work if it works once.

Comment: If it works, it depends on the result of wp_get_attachment_url. Most of the times, wp_get_attachment_url returns url, but it can fail sometimes and in that case it returns false.
The cases are:
1) can not find post (function get_post fails)
2) post_type of the post is not "attachment"
3) returned url would be an empty string, false, zero, ... whatever function empty resolves as true